# Command While in file test (Infinite looping) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I need to validate a parameter in the response of a `GET` with the value `CONFIRMED`. However, this value is updated asynchronously.

I thought about adding a while loop, but it's not working.

```js
while (expect(res.body.content[0].trxConfirmationStatus.id) != 'CONFIRMED') {
              
}
```

The problem is that it keeps in infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe I think you want to apply [Request Polling](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Request-Polling)

This is simply repeating the request until the required response has been found.

```js
function req () {
  cy.request(...).then((resp) => {
    if (resp.body.content[0].trxConfirmationStatus.id) === 'CONFIRMED') {
      return
    }
    req()
  })
}

cy.get('button').click()
  .then(req)
```